# Whats the point of using routes in PHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes

Im trying to learn to work with Laravel, now i see that you got routes in Laravel and other MVC frameworks.
Whats the point of using these routes?
I couldnt find a simple answer to this question.

Comment: A route is simply "this URL is handled by this piece of code". Could you elaborate on what's confusing to you about it?

Comment: Maybe some code will help?  I wrote a simple router for another question a while back, you can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Router).  It works on the same principal as any MVC router.  Basically they use the URI component of the URL.

Comment: The URI is the part following the physical file `example.com/index.php/something` so it `something` in this example, then the `index.php` is hidden using Mod Rewrite.  This is better then using (for example) the GET part of the URL as some other "pretty" URL things do, because in those you loose the ability to properly use the query string in the URL.  And overall, the rewrite rules are much simpler, because you are hiding the `index.php` in all cases, and not trying to map a query string to a URL, which can vary from URL to URL.

Comment: The structure used for calling 'this piece of code' (as explained by @ceejayoz)
is often of the form: controller/action/parameter. So the route basically invokes a method(action) in a controller class (possibly with parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes is where you determines which **controllers** and **actions** are executed based on the **URL** requested.

*Note: this answer is language agnostic*